# Unexpected exception from downstream java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException

Tags: netty

I am new to Netty and the issue which i am facing is , Netty works for some days and after a 5-6 days it doesnot respond.

I checked the errors in logs, which says

```
Nov 26, 2013 11:58:17 PM com.spciq.eventmanagement.connection.MsgServerHandler exceptionCaught
WARNING: Unexpected exception from downstream.
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.cleanUpWriteBuffer(AbstractNioWorker.java:409)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.writeFromUserCode(AbstractNioWorker.java:127)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketPipelineSink.handleAcceptedSocket(NioServerSocketPipelineSink.java:99)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketPipelineSink.eventSunk(NioServerSocketPipelineSink.java:36)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.write(Channels.java:725)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.oneone.OneToOneEncoder.doEncode(OneToOneEncoder.java:71)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.oneone.OneToOneEncoder.handleDownstream(OneToOneEncoder.java:59)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.oneone.OneToOneEncoder.handleDownstream(OneToOneEncoder.java:60)
    at com.spciq.eventmanagement.connection.MsgUser.notifyUser(MsgUser.java:274)
    at com.spciq.eventmanagement.connection.MsgUser.onMessage(MsgUser.java:177)
    at com.hazelcast.impl.ListenerManager.callListener(ListenerManager.java:419)
    at com.hazelcast.impl.ListenerManager.callListeners(ListenerManager.java:334)
    at com.hazelcast.impl.BaseManager$2.run(BaseManager.java:1391)
    at com.hazelcast.impl.executor.ParallelExecutorService$ParallelExecutorImpl$ExecutionSegment.run(ParallelExecutorService.java:212)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.hazelcast.impl.ExecutorThreadFactory$1.run(ExecutorThreadFactory.java:38)
```

Can someone please help me in solving this. This is affecting our Prod Chat client

Answer (score 0):

This means the channel was closed before everything was written out. Without know more about you application it's hard to tell what the problem is. It may be that the remote peer has closed the connection before you was able to write everything out or that you closed it before.

Comment: We're using Jboss Netty and have Hazelcast. Please let me know if you need any config files to refer ?

Comment: Also, is the above exception related to code or due to some issue in configuration files, like keep-alive-seconds is set to 60

Comment: <executor-service>
        <core-pool-size>16</core-pool-size>
        <max-pool-size>64</max-pool-size>
        <keep-alive-seconds>60</keep-alive-seconds>
    </executor-service>
This is what i have in hazelcast-distribution.xml